# How to pass and show validation error from service in child component angular4 below particular input tag

Tags: angular, validation

I am using Angular 4 reactive form and have created a directive (called in parent input and child input separately) to show the errors below each input field if someone write and removes the content, the error is shown below that field (a new div element is created) but now I want to show the errors in parent as well as child component when I submit the form (submit button is in parent class)

Comment: what you have done so far can you please provide code?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).Post a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable [example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Create a message service and store all the validation error message to it. Upon submit  display the content if any.

Also you can keep them in separate arrays or whatsoever you like and display accordingly.

HTH

Comment: I assume you have separate component and they have parent child relation. Now use ViewChild in the parent and validate all at once Incase you don’t want to use message service. But the best solution is to store identifier of the input field and error message in single service shared by both component and upon submit show them to the user. You can’t open both forms at once to show them error.